# Selecting multiple rows from specific categories in SQL

Tags: sql, select, categories

I want to be able to run a report that will give me a list of all the items in the User Computer, Server, and Virtual Machine categories.

I want to exclude all other categories from this report.

I'm not quite sure what to write in order to achieve this, or where to put it.

This is what I'm working with currently. I get an Error Code 1054: Unknown column for each of the categories though...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ASSET.NAME AS ASSET_NAME,
ASSET_TYPE.NAME AS ASSET_TYPE,
ASSET_TYPE.ASSET_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY 
FROM ASSET, ASSET_TYPE
WHERE ASSET_CATEGORY IN (SERVERS, USER_COMPUTER, VIRTUAL_MACHINE)
ORDER BY ASSET.NAME;
```

**EDIT:** I made the suggested changes (from Codo), but now I'm getting 0 rows returned. Any further suggestions?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). Please stop using it

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've only been doing this for two days now. Not quite sure what I got myself into!

Answer (score 2):

Your categories most likely are string and thus need quotes around them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ASSET.NAME AS ASSET_NAME,
ASSET_TYPE.NAME AS ASSET_TYPE,
ASSET_TYPE.ASSET_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY 
FROM ASSET, ASSET_TYPE
WHERE ASSET_CATEGORY IN ('SERVERS', 'USER_COMPUTER', 'VIRTUAL_MACHINE')
ORDER BY ASSET.NAME;
```

Without quotes, the database thinks these words are column names and gets confused.

Furthermore, you query two tables but don't specify how they connect with either other, i.e. there is a join condition missing.

Most likely you need something like:

```
FROM ASSET, ASSET_TYPE
WHERE ASSET_CATEGORY IN ('SERVERS', 'USER_COMPUTER', 'VIRTUAL_MACHINE')
AND ASSET_TYPE.ID  =  ASSET.ASSET_TYPE_ID
```

Comment: That's a good bet... and you might be constructing a Cartesian product there, since there's no join clause.

Comment: I can't figure out why anyone is upvoting this without the join condition.

Comment: Here comes the join condition.

Answer (score 1):

As @Codo said, your categories should be strings (varchar or nvarchar) and should be like

```
WHERE ASSET_CATEGORY IN ('SERVERS', 'USER_COMPUTER', 'VIRTUAL_MACHINE')
```

Also have not shown any relationship of two tables. Assuming the relation is;

```
ASSET.AssetTypeId = ASSET_TYPE.AssetTypeId
```

And ***`avoiding`*** `WHERE ASSET, ASSET_TYPE` type ***`old style table joining`***, your query can be done with table aliases as;

```
SELECT a.NAME ASSET_NAME, at.NAME ASSET_TYPE, at.ASSET_CATEGORY CATEGORY 
FROM ASSET a JOIN ASSET_TYPE at ON a.AssetTypeId = at.AssetTypeId 
WHERE at.ASSET_CATEGORY IN ('SERVERS', 'USER_COMPUTER', 'VIRTUAL_MACHINE')
ORDER BY a.NAME;
```

Comment: And you can skip the `DISTINCT`too (as it was probably added to cancel the cartesian product)

Comment: @ypercube, yep that is true. Took it off. tnx